# Java IB API/ TWS get mulitple quotes/price of the company

Tags: java

Am using java ib api / traders workstaion, now am getting current price for company using ticketprice, is there anyway to  get multiple quotes

Comment: multiple company like AAPL,IBKR etc price in single call/contract.

Comment: Contract contract = createContract("AAPL", "STK", "SMART", "USD");

            // Requests snapshot market data
            eClientSocket.reqMktData(requestId++, contract, null, true);

Comment: am using above code to get one company price,but i need multiple company price

Answer (score 0):

This is not how the IB API works.  Each security quote has a unique ID associated with it.  Therefore, requests must be sent one-at-a-time.